# Mobile redirect and looping error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on small CMS, I changed all originals directories to my desired directories through `RewriteRule` in `htaccess`, Also add mobile template for mobile device users. So my website has two directories, one for Computer client and one for Mobile client, I using the following code to detect mobiles agent and redirect to mobile template but looping errors occur, Any ideas !?

This is my redirect code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

This is my current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Change main URL 
RewriteRule ^m/ /mobile/index.php [QSA]
# Change content URL
RewriteRule ^/a/m/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$ /mobile/index.php?pid=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Try to remove slash from condition RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^m/.*$

Comment: @V.Melnychuk I tried but did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the URI also isn't the rewritten URI (`/mobile/...`). You can do that by either checking against `%{THE_REQUEST}` or include a check for `/mobile`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\ /m/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: @AliGhanei it's because the relative URI base has changed (from `/` with `/mobile` to `/m/` or `/a/m/`). You need to either use absolute URL's or include a `<base href="/">` in the header of your pages.

Comment: Why this code block my other links while I using absolute url?

Comment: @AliGhanei Are there resources like images, scripts, etc that **should not be redirected to `/m/` or `/mobile/`**?